# What happens to the lock when thread crashes inside a Synchronized block?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

lets say Thread-1 synchronizes on object

```
synchronize(object){
  //statement1
  //statement2
  //statement3
}
```

what happens to the lock on object if Thread-1 crashes on statement2, will JVM release the lock on Thread-1 automatically when this happens ? because otherwise if Thread-2 is wating for the lock on object to be released and Thread-1 crashes, the Thread-2 will wait forever.

Comment: Just to be sure, threads don't "crash".  They can throw an exception but they don't segfault or core dump like C.  You can get the [very] odd JVM fault but in that case the whole Java process comes down.  This happens extremely rarely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is defined in the [JLS #14.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19):

```
synchronized ( Expression ) Block
```

> If execution of the Block completes abruptly for any reason, then the monitor is unlocked and the synchronized statement completes abruptly for the same reason.

Comment: thanks a lot @assylias and all others (@Tudor,@dty and @pst) for the responses.

Comment: @assylias if we are using Lock.lock()  API of java.util.concurrent package and we are not releasing lock inside finally block as recommended, but rather we release it inside try block and thread crashes in-between does it also release lock automatically.

Comment: @legend no, if you don't unlock it it will remain locked - [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) clearly states that the lock should be unlocked in a finally block, unless you introduce a mechanism to unlock the lock even if there is an exception - but that's more complicated.

Comment: @assylias does the JLS provides guarantee regarding synchronized block s.t. if a thread acquires the lock then the thread will execute the synchronize block completely and it can't be unscheduled by thread scheduler?

Comment: @YugSingh I'm not sure - you could ask that as a separate question and I'm sure you would get some answers.

Answer (score 6):

You should think of the `synchronized` block:

```
synchronized(lock) {
   // code
}
```

as being the equivalent of (pseudocode):

```
lock.acquire();
try {
   // code
} finally {
   lock.release();
}
```

Thus, the lock will be released, no matter what happens in the code section.

Comment: You are assuming the finally will run. What would happen if the thread crashes due to some reason.

Comment: @Geek: AFAIK the only way the `finally` block won't execute is if the entire JVM crashes, but in that case releasing the lock becomes irrelevant.

Comment: I think I agree with you too. That might be because of the way finally is implemented. Assuming a finally is copied on to the Stack as a miniature function, this looks a feasible case. However if I dump or throw away the thread stack completely I don't think finally can run at all. I am not challenging your thoughts, just trying to understand this more :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the monitor (not lock) will be released.

The Java VM spec will be specific about this if you wish to read it.

The exact reference in the JVM spec can be found in [section 2.11.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.10)

> When invoking a method for which ACC_SYNCHRONIZED is set, the executing thread enters a monitor, invokes the method itself, and exits the monitor whether the method invocation completes normally or abruptly. During the time the executing thread owns the monitor, no other thread may enter it. If an exception is thrown during invocation of the synchronized method and the synchronized method does not handle the exception, *the monitor for the method is automatically exited before the exception is (re)thrown out of the synchronized method.*

Comment: This is *technically* talking about synchronized methods, though.

Comment: That would be the case when a normal execution happens or Exception(Catched/Uncatched) happens. What happens when the thread gets killed as in native threads due to overwriting of a memory location.