# What will happen if thread throws a Exception inside synchronised block

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider multiple threads are trying to access critical section, what will happen one thread that occurs Exception  inside a synchronized block it having wait() and notify() to accrue and release lock.

Comment: This is answered here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521776/what-happens-to-the-lock-when-thread-crashes-inside-a-synchronized-block and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019339/side-effects-of-throwing-an-exception-inside-a-synchronized-clause

Comment: @KennethClark  
what will happen that lock was not manually released. if makes any dead locks

Comment: The lock is guaranteed to be terminated in all cases

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side effects of throwing an exception inside a synchronized clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019339/side-effects-of-throwing-an-exception-inside-a-synchronized-clause)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The synchronization monitor will be released: "If execution of the body is ever completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is automatically performed on that same monitor." Java Language Specification [17.1. Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1).

Other threads will be able to continue synchronizing, and calling wait and notify.

If the thread with the exception is holding some critical program logic resource, you may need to use try-finally to ensure it is released.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are thinking of locks in the same way as resources(Connections, I/O) but unlike resources lock will be released as soon as the executing Thread reaches the exit boundary of critical section(monitor/ synchronized block closing parenthesis) regardless of Exception being thrown.

Refer: [synchronized statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19)

> If execution of the Block completes abruptly for any reason, then the monitor is unlocked and the synchronized statement completes abruptly for the same reason.

Comment: then that lock will automatically release is it

Comment: Yes, in case of exception the monitor is unlocked and the `synchronized` statement completes abruptly thus releasing the lock(monitor)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned if an exception occurs then it should be handled/thrown to continue the execution or else execution will stop. So, it is same in your scenario if an exception happens then it would be handled and further the lock will be released.

Comment: what will happen that lock was not manually released. if makes any dead locks

Comment: Generally, we should take care of all scenarios to avoid possibility of dead locks. If any dead lock is invoked then we can't do anything from our end except restarting the application. To avoid deadlocks I suggest you to read about "Inter-Thread Communication in Java".