# What happens if a thread executing a synchronised method suspends?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

What happens if a thread executing a `synchronized` method suspends? Will other Threads get the lock and proceed with another `synchronized` method in the same class..?

Suppose the code is like:

```
class Test{
   public synchronized void methodA(){
      //methodA
   }
   public synchronized void methodB(){
      //methodB
   }
}
```

If `ThreadA` execute `methodA()`. And while executing the method if it get suspended implicitly by the OS. Will another Thread, say `ThreadB` can get the lock and execute `methodB()`? or is it possible only after the `ThreadA` completes its work with `methodA()`?

Comment: [What will happen if thread throws a Exception inside synchronised block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660236/what-will-happen-if-thread-throws-a-exception-inside-synchronised-block), [What happens to the lock when thread crashes inside a Synchronized block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521776/what-happens-to-the-lock-when-thread-crashes-inside-a-synchronized-block)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't force the thread to relinquish the lock since it would break the whole idea of synchronization. It is possible to exit the monitor via `wait` method call on the object (declared in the `Object` class) to give other threads a chance to enter it .

Answer (score 0):

Following text from book [Java - The Complete Reference](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/java-the-complete/9781260440249/ch11.xhtml#ch11)  should help :

> This was done because suspend( ) can sometimes cause serious system
> failures. Assume that a thread has obtained locks on critical data
> structures. If that thread is suspended at that point, those locks are
> not relinquished. Other threads that may be waiting for those
> resources can be deadlocked.